# search an area throughout

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Is "throughout" used properly in the following, witht the meaning that they searched every part of the area? Is not, could you explain why it's not okay?

> Police searched the area throughout.

Answer (score 1):

This may be understood three ways:

- [Throughout](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/throughout) may be used as an adverb, modifying "searched".
- "Police searched throughout the area." Here, "throughout," serves as a preposition. Inverted or changed word order is not uncommon in English, perhaps for emphasis. "Yes, that's the store I sent him to."
- It is not uncommon in casual English to omit parts of a phrase, where it is clearly understood. For example, in the sentence, "Go!" the subject, "you," is omitted, though by certain grammatical rules, every sentence has a subject. This is called [conversational deletion](https://learnenglishwithdemi.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/conversational-deletion/) and [ellipsis](https://www.thoughtco.com/ellipsis-grammar-and-rhetoric-1690640).

  Police searched the area throughout [the building].
  *In the context of the story*, "the building," or perhaps, "the district," is understood.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English?

Comment: @Apollyon, Ναι, είμαι φυσικός ομιλητής Αγγλικών.

Comment: In Go! the subject is omitted because it is an imperative verb form....

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is absolutely correct. Here are a few more examples from the dictionary:

*They painted the house throughout.*

*The house is carpeted throughout.*

In these sentences, "throughout" is an adverb. There's no need to say anything after that word.

*They searched the area throughout = They searched the whole area.*